# What does BNL2 Schengen Visa mean? I have one from Netherlands. Can I travel to Spain now?

Tags: schengen, spain, netherlands

I have a valid multiple entry Schengen visa from Netherlands Embassy. It says BNL2 and type of Visa as "C". I went to Netherlands on business visit.

I want to travel to Spain now for tennis training of my daughter. Can I travel to Spain on the same visa now?

Comment: It is probably read as "Business NetherLands", unsure what 2 stands for. C-type visas are valid across the whole zone.

Comment: Thanks Bipil but as per other internet search, BNL2 means benelux 2 ( bruxelles, nederland, and Luxembourg). Hence, I am confused that whether it is a business Visa or I can also travel on leisure? Thanks!

Comment: _Belgium_, Netherlands, and Luxembourg

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "business" and "tourist" visa in the Schengen system. There are only *uniform short-stay visas*, which is what you have.

Given that the visa is multiple-entry, the *point* of being multiple entry is that you can use it for any subsequent visit to anywhere in the Schengen area that satisfies the rules for a short visit.

Comment: this is not correct. There is the standard Visitor and a Business visa, where by Visitor is mostly included with a Business visa. Depending on the issuer this is an entry in the remark field of the Visa.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: Have they changed the rules within the last few months? Please provide a reliable source for that claim.

Comment: @MarkJohnson some countries make that entry and others do not.  The presence of such an annotation on a multiple-entry visa does not prevent the bearer from using the visa for a different purpose on a subsequent trip.

Comment: No. Look at the application form. Look at the visa image here       https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/146788/95267 Where by the way are your sources?

Comment: @MarkJohnson the application form requires the applicant to disclose the purpose of the visit. That does not cause the visa to be of a different category. The annotations you speak of are governed by national law, not the Schengen codes.  See Annex 22 linked in my answer.

Comment: @phoog I have. BNL13 business poupose. inGermany it is a text For Czech C/VB/01/-/--; called commercial. So making the claim that it does not exist is false.

Comment: @MarkJohnson sure, but there's nothing in the codes that prevents someone with a multiple-entry visa issued for tourist purposes from later using that visa for a business trip, nor vice versa.  I see nothing in the German [Aufenthaltsgesetz](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/) or [Aufenthaltsverordnung](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/index.html) that forbids this, either.  An annotation in the "comments" section of a visa does not create a new category of visa.

Comment: @phoog if the visa states visitor, then Business is not permitted. Extra conditions exist for the issuing. There is a reason why the Embassies themselfs use this terminology. The Embassy terminology should not be contradicted here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98741/discussion-between-phoog-and-mark-johnson).

Answer (score 1):

According to [Annex 22](https://www.ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/doc_centre/borders/docs/Annex%2022_COMMENTS%20SECTION_14.2.2011_EN.pdf) of the [Handbook for the processing of visa applications and the
modification of issued visas](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf), BNL2 is the code for a visa issued by Belgium, the Netherlands, or Luxembourg "ex officio."   I don't quite know what *that* means, however.

Regardless, Henning Makholm's [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/117470/19400) is correct: it does not restrict your use of the visa.  To impose any restriction, there would be a less cryptic annotation describing the restriction.